# Order by value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm just practising with python. I have a dictionary in the form:

```
my_dict = [{'word': 'aa', 'value': 2}, 
           {'word': 'aah', 'value': 6}, 
           {'word': 'aahed', 'value': 9}]
```

How would I go about ordering this dictionary such that if I had thousands of words I would then be able to select the top 100 based on their value ranking? e.g., from just the above example:

```
scrabble_rank = [{'word': 'aahed', 'rank': 1},
                 {'word': 'aah', 'rank': 2}, 
                 {'word': 'aa', 'rank': 3}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, that's not a dictionary; it's a list of dictionaries. Which is good, because dictionaries are unordered, but lists are ordered.

You can sort the list by the value of the `rank` element by using it as a key to the sort function:

```
scrabble_rank.sort(key=lambda x: x['value'])
```

Comment: Hmmm, this is quite cool - I will accept but this orders from "worst" to "best" value - so for three items with values 2, 5, 8, it should be ordered 8, 5, 2 - highest to lowest...

Comment: I can use reverse=True as one of the args for the sort function.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts using `my_dict.sort(key=lambda x: -x['value'])` does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
scrabble_rank = [{'word':it[1], 'rank':idx+1} for idx,it in enumerate(sorted([[item['value'],item['word']] for item in my_dict],reverse=True))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Pandas` Library:

```
import pandas as pd
```

There is this one-liner:

```
scrabble_rank = pd.DataFrame(my_dict).sort_values('value', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True).reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
```

It outputs:

```
[{'index': 0, 'value': 9, 'word': 'aahed'},
 {'index': 1, 'value': 6, 'word': 'aah'},
 {'index': 2, 'value': 2, 'word': 'aa'}]
```

Basically it reads your records into a DataFrame, then it sort by `value` in descending order, then it drops original index (order), and it exports as records (your previous format).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html):

```
import heapq

my_dict = [{'word': 'aa', 'value': 2}, 
           {'word': 'aah', 'value': 6}, 
           {'word': 'aahed', 'value': 9}]

# Select the top 3 records based on `value`
values_sorted = heapq.nlargest(3, # fetch top 3
                               my_dict, # dict to be used
                               key=lambda x: x['value']) # Key definition
print(values_sorted)
[{'word': 'aahed', 'value': 9}, {'word': 'aah', 'value': 6}, {'word': 'aa', 'value': 2}]
```